# selenium убрать в Chrome окно leave site changes you made may not be saved

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

Пробую перейти на другую страницу, но не могу потому что не закончил процесс (когда написал сообщение, но не отправил (может потому то другая форма появилась для написания сообщения), но уйти со страницы тоже не может), вылазит окно:

[image: ошибка при переключении экрана]

Пробую топорным способом но не всегда срабатывает

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
...                driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ESCAPE)
                driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ESCAPE)
                driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ENTER)
```

Как это окно убрать или закрыть?

Answer (score 0):

В опциях запуска браузера добавь:

Chrome:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking")
```

Firefox:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('dom.disable_beforeunload', True)
```

На 100% уверен в Firefox, проверил - работает.

Answer (score 0):

void accept() кликает на кнопку “Ok”, как только появляется всплывающее окно
void dismiss() кликает на кнопку “Cancel”, как только появляется всплывающее окно

Comment: как в python это написать, на примере?